# I can't activate GO111MODULE

Tags: go, go-modules

I want to use go modules, after a lot of searching, I just saw some website that said, enable go111module with this command:

```
GO111MODULE=on
```

But it's not a path variable, it does not even exist on my pc, so it shows me

```
GO111MODULE is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
program, or batch file.
```

Some people said it's enabled by default on GO v1.16 but it's not working for me,
How do I understand it's not working?

I use:

```
go mod init
```

and

```
go get <some_packages>
```

It adds the new package to my go.mod but my code can't recognize it and I have an "Unresolved dependency" error in my go.mod file.

I use Goland to solve my problem using their GUI's and it solved my problem but their settings just work on the current project and don't work globally.

What can I do? (I'm a Windows 10 user, Go version 1.16)

### Answer (Update):

Set a path variable like this by yourself:

[image: I can't activate GO111MODULE]

After that, run the command:

```
go env
```

You will have this line at first line:

```
set GO111MODULE=on
```

Comment: "Some people said it's enabled by default on GO v1.16 but I'm sure it's not!" -- Well, it is on by default. You can read this in the [official Go 1.16 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command). Why do you think it's not?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Flimzy excuse me because I didn't say my problem well.
Actually, it's not "on" because I make it on with Goland Settings and it starts working and recognizing packages. I'm trying to find a way to enable go modules for all of my projects not for every project and not just with Goland settings.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. Now it's a tiny bit closer to explaining your problem, but still not there. You say "I have an import error". WHAT error?

Comment: @Flimzy Unresolved dependency in go.mod file.

Comment: Do not put answers in the question. Answers belong as answers.

Comment: Also, that answer is wrong. 1. That's not a "path variable" (whatever that is). 2. It's unnecessary as we've already discussed, becuase on is the default for Go 1.16.

Comment: Nobody doubts that your problem is real. However, the question is very _unclear_. This is why the question was closed. And all of that is completely irrelevant to the fact that answers _do not belong in questions_.

Comment: @Flimzy I passed 2 complete days to solve this problem, I said two ways to solve this problem, You closed my question and it forced me to answer in an update because I wanted to help others don't waste their time on solving this problem like me.
I edited this post a lot, to be more clear, but now It's so simple: """go get adds the new package to my go.mod but my code can't recognize it and I have an "Unresolved dependency" error in my go.mod file."""

Comment: I don't think you're listening to what I'm saying. There's nothing wrong with your answer, per se. There's nothing wrong with your problem.

Comment: The only problem is that you did not ask a clear question. If you can clarify your question, it can be reopened. Then you can answer it properly.

Comment: Abusing the question to provide an answer is NOT a solution to an unclear question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its not a path variable.
It is a go environmental variable.
Yes is is available by default actually.

On your terminal, type

```
go env | grep "GO111MODULE"
```

That should show you what that variable is set to
You can try the same with other go env variables eg GOPROXY, GOPRIVATE etc just to satisfy yourself.

The output `GO111MODULE=""` means it is **on** (since [Go 1.16](https://go.dev/blog/go116-module-changes))

Comment: It says: "'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
In my go env there is something like this: "set GO111MODULE= " and "set GOMOD=NUL", in front of "GO111MODULE=" there is just empty space.